# How to create Pascal?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, 4gl

I am very difficult to display all the output results.

this code.

DEF VAR INPUTAN AS INTEGER.
DEF VAR i AS INTEGER.
DEF VAR j AS INTEGER.
DEF VAR a AS INTEGER.
DEF VAR rows AS INT.
DEF VAR pascal AS CHAR FORMAT "x(25)".

SET INPUTAN.
a = 1.

REPEAT i = 0 TO INPUTAN:
rows = i.
DISPLAY rows.
REPEAT j = 0 TO i :

IF  j = 0 OR j = i THEN DO:
a = 1.
END.
ELSE

a = a * (i + 1 - j) / j.

pascal = STRING(a).

display a.

END.
END.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DEF VAR INPUTAN AS INTEGER. 
DEF VAR i AS INTEGER. 
DEF VAR j AS INTEGER. 
DEF VAR a AS INTEGER. 
DEF VAR rows AS INT. 
DEF VAR pascal AS CHAR.

SET INPUTAN. 
a = 1.

REPEAT i = 0 TO INPUTAN:
    
 rows = i. 
 /*DISPLAY rows. */
 
 REPEAT j = 0 TO i :

   IF j = 0 OR j = i THEN DO: 
      a = 1. 
   END. 
   ELSE
      a = a * (i + 1 - j) / j.

   IF j = 0 THEN
      pascal = pascal + FILL("   ", INPUTAN - i).
   pascal = pascal + STRING(a) + "   ".

   IF j = i THEN
      pascal = pascal + CHR(13).

 /*  display a.*/

 END. 

END.

MESSAGE pascal
   VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFO BUTTONS OK.
```

Comment: already working but not tidy
the result is 1 by one line

is there any solution..??

Comment: thaks brother for suport :)

Comment: @StefanDrissen 

your code error in "do j = 0 to irow:"

Comment: Sorry, I was giving the variables more meaningful names since I have an intense dislike for i and j, but then couldn’t be bothered anymore, change def var i to def var j - abldojo does not want to give my iPad the updated link.

Comment: updated example https://abldojo.services.progress.com/?shareId=60d2d3539585066c2197996d